# Storing Data from a FirebaselistObservable or Use InnerHtml?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm currently developing an Ionic application with help of Angular 4. I also have AngularFire2 and Firebase as my backend. When a user goes offline in my app, I want them to be able to retrieve the latest data that they queried from the firebase. Now, I have two approaches to this. One would be to use the `{preservesnapshot: true}` option when retrieving the data and then use `forEach` to iterate over the list's items and store them into the local storage. However, in my template, I'm displaying the list items using the async pipe (which makes it a lot easier to deal with). In this way, I was thinking of giving each item in the list a specific id, and then storing the `innerHtml` property of each id:d list item into the storage. Which one would be the most efficient here? Many online argue that preserveSnapshot and storing firebaselist-data into arrays should be avoided, so I'm curious as to what would be most efficient or the best approach.

Comment: Do you need to work offline use case with the firebase?

Comment: @Sampath I don't need to push data or change anything while offline, no. All I want is to be able to display the data to the user even though they are offline (if they have previously connected). You could think of it as blog information, but I don't want the data to disappear because the user restarts the app.

Comment: OK, then you can cache the data and use when offline use case no? I have implemented such thing with Ionic cache API.Do you need to know about that or ?

Comment: Yes, do you have any experience with angularfire?

Comment: Yes, I do have.What do you need to know?

Comment: I want to know how I could store data from a FirebaseListObservable straight into an array on the device. After this, I want to store this into my local storage using the storage plugin.

Comment: @Sampath see aboove comment

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below.Hope you know how to handle the `storage` module.

```
this.myList = af.database.list('/myList/', {
    query: {}, preserveSnapshot:true
    });

this.myList.subscribe(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(snapshot => {
             this.myArray.push(snapshot); //your array here
         });
   });
```